# displaying the file from servlet after uploading

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, file-upload

I uploaded a file using servlet, using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet?rq=1) source but problem is it seems my browser doesnt seem to access the file **from servlet** that is when i use out.println() .when i copy the same source and open it from notepad it is showing fine. when i tried opening it using firefox it gave the error, it dint even mind while opening in chrome.

```
 Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because the protocol (d) isn't associated with any program.
```

what is wrong going on. how to open the file.

Answer (score 0):

Open up Firebug and see the response you are getting back from the server.